# Creating a dictionary with LINQ and keys from nested list

Tags: linq

I have code that looks like this:

```
class A {
public string Name {get;set;}
public IList<string> Keywords {get;set;}
}
```

...

```
IList<A> a = new List<A>{
        new A{Name = "a1", Keywords = new List<string>{"k1", "k2"}},
        new A{Name = "a2", Keywords = new List<string>{"k1", "k3"}},
        new A{Name = "a3", Keywords = new List<string>{"k3", "k4"}},
        new A{Name = "a4", Keywords = new List<string>{"k1", "k3", "k4"}}
    };
```

Is there any way I can use LINQ to create a dictionary in the form of:

```
{"k1", List<A> {a1, a2, a4}} 
{"k2", List<A> {a1}}
{"k3", List<A> {a2, a3, a4}}
{"k4", List<A> {a3, a4}}
```

Basically mapping the objects to the keywords.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
var dict = a
    .SelectMany(myA =>
        myA.Keywords.Select(kw => new { Name = myA.Name, Keyword = kw }))
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.Keyword)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(pair => pair.Name).ToList());
```

should do it.

Answer (score 1):

That should do it:

```
var keywordsAndNames = a.SelectMany(anA => anA.Keywords.Select(kw => 
                           new { KeyWord = kw, Name = anA.Name }));
var lookup = keywordsAndNames.ToLookup(entry => entry.KeyWord, entry => entry.Name);
```

Note that this code creates a lookup and not a dictionary because for each key there are multiple names.

`lookup["k1"]` returns an `IEnumerable<string>` yielding "a1", "a2" and "a4" for instance.

Comment: If OP doesn't _really_ need a list then this should be more efficient than my version :)